# Definition of inverse function

Tags: calculus, definition, taylor-expansion, inverse

I have been wondering... Is there a mathematical equation for the inverse of a function? I mean apart from the typical "replace the x's with y's" way... I tried using the inverse function derivative and integral but only got a circular answer! If this isn't possible, what about Taylor series or some other sort of series? Note, the answers shouldn't be circular, meaning the definition of the inverse shouldn't include the inverse...

(Also, please tell me what is wrong with my question or whether there was a duplicate I didn't find so I can fix this question or delete it.)

Comment: "Replace $x$'s with $y$'s" does not give the inverse of a function, but I understand where you're coming from. No, there's no general rule for finding the inverse of a function.

Comment: Functions themselves aren't necessarily even defined by equations.

Comment: Indeed, there isn't always an inverse.

Comment: One of the deeper results of algebra is (roughly) that there isn't a formula using roots even for the (local) inverse of the general polynomial of degree 5.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews but if the function can be written in Taylor series, then it would be easier...correct? Or am I just saying rubbish?

Comment: A polynomial is just a Taylor series with only finitely many non-zero terms. @TAbraham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the very particular case of an analytic function, there is a relatively explicit formula for the inverse. See [Lagrange inversion theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem).

The general formula is: for $f(w)=z$ with $f'(a)\ne 0$,
$$f^{-1}(z)=a+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\lim_{w\to a}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\left(\frac{w-a}{f(w)-f(a)}\right)^n\right)\frac{(z-f(a))^n}{n!}.$$
In the special case $f(w)=w/\phi(w)$, can be reduced to the easier form
$$[z^n]f^{-1}(z)=\frac1n[w^{n-1}]\phi(w)^n$$
($[\cdot]$ is the coefficient of the corresponding power)

A very interesting example is the deduction of the coefficients of Lambert function, defined by $z=w/e^w$:
$$[z^n]w=\frac1n[w^{n-1}]e^{nw}=\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(nw)^k}{k!}=\frac{n^{n-1}}{n!}.$$

For several proofs, see [Lagrange Inversion Formula](http://www.math.msu.edu/~magyar/Math880/Lagrange.pdf) by Peter Magyar, [Proof of the Lagrange Inversion Formula](http://people.math.carleton.ca/~zgao/MATH5819/Notes/NoteT6.pdf) by Jason Z. Gao, or (maybe paywalled) [An algebraic proof of the Lagrange-Bürmann formula](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X64900630) by Peter Henrici.

Comment: Can you explain what this is?  Also, this won't give a formula for ln x, correct?

Comment: It will give a formula for $\ln x$ around anything other than zero, actually. @TAbraham

Comment: @TAbraham, it will give a explicit formula for $\log(x-x_0)$ ($x_0\ne 0$) *if* you can do all the calculuations.

Comment: Can you show a proof (if it isn't too complex!)? Also can you put the formula and how to use it so this answer can get accepted?

Comment: I didn't understand the special case, what is the ϕ(w), is it just another function? and is w=x ?

Comment: @TAbraham, the particular case is when $f$ has the *form* $f(w)=w/\phi(w)$ with $\phi$ *another* function. When the variables are complex is customary to use the letters $z$ and $w$, but you can use $x$, $y$ if you want.